# postgresql outputting pg_query img url data in href

Tags: php, jquery, postgresql

i want to printf pg_guery returning data which is actually image url, in href quotation.. but i cannot do that. i will make a fancybox by these results

here is my codes

```
<?php
        $sqli=pg_query("SELECT bimurl, simgurl FROM images WHERE imgid=$yerId");
        echo "<p>"
        while($resulti=pg_fetch_array($resulti)){
            printf ("<a class='fancybox-thumbs' data-fancybox-group='thumb' href='.%s'.jpg'><img src='.%s.'.jpg' alt='' /></a>" , $resulti['bimurl'], $resulti['simgurl']);

        }

        echo"</p>"
```

edit: I solved it by using **printf** as shown below:

```
             printf ('<a class="fancybox-thumbs" data-fancybox-group="thumb" href="'.$resulti['bimgurl'].'.jpg"><img src="'.$resulti['simgurl'].'.jpg" alt="" /></a>');
```

Answer (score 1):

you must make a connection first like this:

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=db_name user=username password=password");
```

then execute query:

```
$result = pg_query($dbconn, "SELECT bimurl, simgurl FROM images WHERE imgid=$yerId");
```

then you can loop over result:

```
    while($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){
        do somthings;
    }
```

for more information take a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php)

Comment: what is your question? are you sure data is feteching from database?

Comment: i want to printf pg_guery returning data which is actually image url, in href quotation as i said above.. fetch query return just as "string" ...may be there a mistake with the database or else ?

Comment: thanks you a lot you show me that my query is not true, i fixed it. but still it is not show in the sprintf

Comment: are you sure returned result is in string format? do you have any error or warning?

Comment: no sir, there is not an error appearing...my data type is varchar and i except to return something like "1_b" "1_s"



Edit: i change sprintf to printf and it worked thank you again

true syntax for those who may encounter with same problem is 

                 printf ('<a class="fancybox-thumbs" data-fancybox-group="thumb" href="'.$resulti[bimgurl].'.jpg"><img src="'.$resulti[simgurl].'.jpg" alt="" /></a>');